# Not able to fetch url params in vue js

Tags: vuejs3

Hi I am trying to fetch the value for "customerID" and "iot" in MyIOT.vue. When I enter the url http://localhost:8080/5/345435 it gives me an empty value for params. I tried both ways using routing and props. None of them is working. Not sure where I am getting it wro

***main.js***

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import MyIot from './components/MyIOT.vue'
//import router from './router/index.js'

const routes = [
    // {
    //     path: '/',
    //     redirect: '/:customerID/:iot'
    // },
    {
        path: '/:customerID/:iot',
        component: MyIot,
        //props: true,
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

const app = createApp(App).use(router);
app.mount('#app');
```

***App.vue***

```html
<template>
  <MyIot />
</template>

<script>
import MyIot from './components/MyIOT.vue'
//import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    MyIot,
  },

};
</script>
```

***components/MyIOT.vue***

```html
<template>
    <div>customer id is: {{customerID}} and iot is : {{iot}} 
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'

    export default {
        name: 'MyIot',
        //props: ['customerID', 'iot'],
        setup() {
            const route = useRoute();
            console.log(route.params);
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with composition API yet so not sure if this use of setup and useRoute makes a difference but with vue-router 4 all navigation is asynchronous so you have to make sure the router is ready before loading components. Try using router.isReady in your main.js? https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-router-4-route-params-not-available-on-created-setup/

Comment: Thanks It helped!!!  router.isReady().then(() => {
    app.mount('#app')
})